A detail on the statement of the dominated convergence theorem
Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ positive measure and, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, consider $f_n:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ a measurable function.
If

$\exists f(x)=\lim_n f_n(x)$ a.e. $x\in X$,
$\exists g\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ such that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x), \hspace{5pt} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and a.e. $x\in X$.

Then,

$f\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$,
$\lim_n\int_X|f_n-f|\ d\mu=0$,
$\lim_n\int_X f_n\ d\mu=\int_X f\ d\mu$.

In the proof that I have, is defined the set $D_0=\{x\in X\hspace{3pt}|\hspace{3pt} \hspace{5pt}\exists \lim_nf_n(x)\in [-\infty,+\infty]\}$ and it needs to be measurable.
My question is, why is $D_0$ measurable? Does it follow directly from convergence hypotheses almost everywhere?

Actually, it is an exercise (see Real Analysis, Folland, 2.1.3) and a nice observation. The catch here is noting that $\limsup f_n$ and $\liminf f_n$ are measurable functions. Can you deduce the rest from this?

Ok, I know that $\limsup_n f_n$ and $\liminf_n f_n$ are measurable, but how can I describe $D_0$ as the pre image through $\lim_nf_n$?

The set where $\lim_n f_n$ exists is the set where $\lim \sup_n f_n = \lim \inf_n f_n$.

Your definiton for $D_0$ has no meaning written like this. $\exists\lim_n f_n(x)$ isn’t a correct notation.

I made an edit to my post.

One way to prove that $D_0$ is measurable is the following:
Given any sequence of measurable functions  $f_n:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$, we have that $\limsup_n f_n$ and $\liminf_n f_n$ are defined in all $x \in X$ and both $\limsup_n f_n$ and $\liminf_n f_n$ are measurable functions. Now note that:
$$ D_0=\{ x \in X : \limsup_n f_n(x) = \liminf_n f_n(x) \}$$
so $D_0$ is measurable.
HOWEVER, without the assumption that $\mu$ is complete, $f$ may not be a measurable, even if $f(x)=\lim_n f_n(x)$ a.e. $x\in X$.
Here is an example:
Let $([0,1], \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra   and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $C$ be the (standard) Cantor set. Then $C$ is Borel measurable, $\lambda(C) = 0$ and we know that there is $E \subseteq C$ such that $E$ is not Borel measurable.
Now, for all $n$, define $f_n=0$, and define $f = \chi_E$ (the indicator function of $E$).
It follows that, for all $n$, $f_n$ is a Borel measurable function and $f(x)=\lim_n f_n(x)$ a.e. $x\in X$, but $f$ is not a Borel measurable function.

Here's an alternative proof to the one in the comments. Define
$$ D_0(n,m,k) := \{x \in X \ : \ |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < 1/k\}.$$
Show that this is a measurable set for each $n$, $m$, and $k$, then show that $$D_0 = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n,m=N}^\infty D_0(n,m,k).$$

I didn't see you were doing the extended reals. This will work when the image of $f_n$ is in $\mathbb{R}$, but you'll have to be careful with $\pm \infty$.
